# String concatenation doesn't work

Tags: string, lazarus, delphi

I created a simple class to store data receive from the serial port and split it following certain conditions. I realize it was not working as excepted, so I recode it step by step to see what was wrong. And I found that it was a string concatenation. Here is the code of the class. The line that fails is the `buffer = buffer + tail;`

```
unit InBuffer;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
    Classes, SysUtils;

type
    TInBuffer = class
        private
            buffer: String;
            messages: TStrings;
        public
            constructor Create;
            destructor Destroy;
            procedure Add(tail: string);
            function getBuffer: String;
            function getLast: String;
            function DataAvailable: boolean;
    end;

implementation

constructor TInBuffer.Create;
begin
    buffer := '';
    messages := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TInBuffer.Destroy;
begin
    messages.Free;
    inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TInBuffer.Add(tail: string);
begin
    buffer := buffer + tail;
end;

function TInBuffer.GetBuffer: String;
begin
    Result := buffer;
end;

function TInBuffer.GetLast: String;
begin
    if DataAvailable then
        begin
        Result := messages[0];
        messages.Delete(0);
        end;
end;

function TInBuffer.DataAvailable: boolean;
begin
    Result := messages.Count > 0;
end;

end.
```

I use [SdpoSerial](http://wiki.freepascal.org/5dpo) for the communication stuff. In the OnRxData event I have this code.

```
procedure TfrmMain.serOnRxData(Sender: TObject);
var
    msg: string;
begin
    msg := ser.ReadData;
    buff.Add(msg);
    log('Stored buffer: ' + buff.getBuffer);
    log('Receive trace: ' + msg);
end;
```

In the log I see the correct data in "Receive trace", but the line in "Stored buffer" is always the same (the first message received in the communication). I've tried using functions like `Copy` or `Concat` to build the buffer, but nothing changes.

What may be I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: 
Following Abelisto's suggestion, I put this code inside a button's onClick event

```
buff.Add('111');
buff.Add('222');
ShowMessage(buff.getBuffer);
```

And the message shown is correct. So there is some problem with passing the data coming from the serial port. It's shown correctly in the log, but not in the buffer. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you try test your class in more simple way, like `buff := TInBuffer.Create; buff.Add('111'); buff.Add('222'); ShowMessage(buff.GetBuffer);`?

Comment: Hi Abelisto. Thanks for this simple idea I should have had. I tried and it works, I got a "111222" in the message.

Comment: So your problem in something else. Good luck.

Comment: Where do you add strings to `messages`?

Comment: I did it in the `Add` function. But as I said, it wasn't working and I started from scratch, going step by step, until I found the problem was the buffer was not buffering at all. Seems to work with hardcoded data (Abelisto's comment), but not with the data obtained from the serial port.

Comment: BTW It will be nice to see the `log` procedure source code. And also some log fragment where you encountered error.

Comment: [This code](http://pastebin.com/1au8HNbU) reproduces your error as I understand.

Comment: `log` is simply this: `logMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime(fmt, now) + line);`. So, some null character issue? I'll check that.

Comment: Try `logMemo.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime(fmt, now) + StringReplace(line, #0, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]));`

Comment: The log is ok, in _Receive trace_ I can see what the serial port receive, but in _Stored buffer_ I see nothing, that's the question. I'll try `StringReplace` with the buffer.

Comment: It works with the `StringReplace`! Thank you very much :D

Comment: Post your investigation as answer. BTW the loop like `for i := 1 to length(s) if s[i] = #0 then s[i] := ' ';` will be much faster then `StringReplace` Note this works with ANSI/ASCII strings only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the external devices like RS232 or so on can post to the port anything you have to be ready for it. In the our case the device post the NULL character which is breaks the string in the C-written OS. The Pascal strings can handle it but not the OS wigets. However I was confused by console like app which is handle the NULL character fine. So be careful.